# Grouping in django admin

Tags: python, django

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from collections import Counter
from django.db.models import Count
from itertools import groupby
Gender = (
    ('Male', 'MALE'),
    ('Female', 'FEMALE'),
)

Diseases = (
    ('Cholera', 'CHOLERA'),
    ('HIV', 'HIV'),
    ('Malaria', 'MALARIA'),
    ('Typhoid', 'TYPHOID'),
    ('Measles', 'MEASLES'),
)


class MyModel(models.Model):
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=Gender, default='MALE')
    Diseases = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=Diseases, default='MALARIA')
    vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
            r=0
            return u'%s %s' % (self.Gender, self.Diseases)
```

Now this returns this in the admin django panel

```
Male Measles
Male Measles
Male Cholera
Female Cholera
Female Typhoid
Female Typhoid
```

But I want to group it so it looks something like this:

```
Male malaria 2
Male Measles 2
Female Typhoid 3
```

in this admin panel instead of listing all of it like it does now

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values) and [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) functions for grouping values

```py
MyModel.objects.values('Gender, Diseases').annotate(Count('Gender'), Count('Diseases'))
```

However, grouping something in the Admin Panel doesn't really makes sense if you want to be able to edit the data. Grouping something removes the identity/primary key of each element and would make it unable to actually choose one element in the objects view.